# VBA to isolate and divide numbers in a string

Tags: excel, vba, database, string, data-cleaning

I would like to divide al the numbers in the string by 100 with a VBA macro, is any of you that kind to help?

The goal is to have the exact same strings but with the numbers divided by 100.

The length of the the column containing the string changes every day

Database:

- KABN Mar22 48000
- VO3 STG Sep22 16000 - 19000
- KABN Apr22 48000 P
- DHE Dec24 3000 P
- ADS PS Dec22 24000 - 20000
- UNI Sep22 3800 P
- ABBN PDIA Apr22 3100 Jun22 3000
- ADS Sep22 18000 P BAS Jun22 6200 P
- BAS Jun22 6800 C
- SGE Jun22 3200 C
- HLA Mar22 20000 P
- MOH Mar22 77000 C
- NOVN STG Sep22 7600 - 8000
- GEBN Dec22 56000 P
- AXA Jun23 1900 P UBSN
- STG Jun22 1800 - 2000
- NOA3 Dec22 700 C
- NOA3 Dec22 700 C
- NOA3 Dec22 600 C
- NOA3 Dec22 600 C

EDIT: the issue is harder that you can think, normal text into columns, split, division for space, isnumeric etc. do not work and overall they are not efficient

Comment: This is a very simple, albeit repetitive task in VBA.  I suggest you start by working your way through a VBA tutorial.  Pay specific attention to the Split Keyword.

Comment: @freeflow `Split` is a great idea! Split each string by the spaces, save the split strings in an array. Test each array element with `IsNumeric` to see if it is a number that can be divided. After dividing, `Join` the array back together with spaces. Done!

Comment: Unfortunately guys your comments are not helpful. Firstly dividing into space just makes the issue more complicated as the numbers do not end up in the same cells and make an alignment function does not worth it. Additionally, I already worked my way on it and worked as well on similar issues, this one is harder that you think.
@toddleson

Comment: @Akibaida you are misunderstanding. In VBA there is a function `Split()` that takes in a delimited string and splits it by the specified delimiter into an array.

Comment: @Akibaida.  Unfortunately, some people like yourself have too little knowledge for the help that is given to be useful.  That's why I recommended doing a VBA tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in comments, consider using `Split()` to split the string into an array, iterating the array, checking if the word is numeric, and then use `join` to stitch it back into a string.

```
Function divideNumBy100(inVal As String) As String
    'Split the incoming string into an array
    wordArr = Split(inVal, " ")
    
    'Loop through each index in the array
    For i = 0 To UBound(wordArr)
    
        'test to seee if the word is numeric
        If IsNumeric(wordArr(i)) Then
        
            'divide by 100
            wordArr(i) = wordArr(i) / 100
        End If
    Next i
    
    '"Join" the array back into a string and return the result to the caller
    divideNumBy100 = Join(wordArr, " ")
End Function
```

You can use that like a regular function in your excel sheet like `=divideNumBy100("this is a 100 test")` and it will return `this is a 1 test`.

Best of luck.

Comment: @Toddleson I could very well be wrong there. It's been a long time since I wrote VBA in a day-to-day. I was thinking that indexes of arrays are 0 based, but Ubound spits out number of elements... I'm guessing I'm wrong there. If that's the case I will be happy to edit.

Comment: Fixed! Thanks for the check  @Toddleson